# how to install mongodb on gentoo?

Tags: linux, gentoo, mongodb

Im trying to install mongodb but as soon as i do

```
emerge dev-db/mongodb
```

i get

```
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/snowball-stemmer-0.20140325::gentoo  USE="- static-libs" 127 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-libs/libunwind-1.1:7::gentoo  USE="-debug -debug-frame -libatomic -lzma -static-libs" 1073 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/google-perftools-2.0-r2:0/4::gentoo  USE="-debug -largepages -minimal -static-libs {-test}" 1232 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-util/scons-2.3.0::gentoo  USE="-doc" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 586 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-cpp/yaml-cpp-0.5.1::gentoo  116 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-arch/snappy-1.1.2-r1::gentoo  USE="-static-libs" ABI_X86="32 (64) (-x32)" 1451 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-db/mongodb-2.6.8::gentoo  USE="ssl -debug -kerberos -mms-agent -static-libs" 14205 KiB

Total: 7 packages (7 new), Size of downloads: 18787 KiB

The following USE changes are necessary to proceed:
(see "package.use" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by dev-db/mongodb-2.6.8::gentoo
# required by dev-db/mongodb (argument)
>=dev-util/google-perftools-2.0-r2 -minimal
```

i'm not sure how to fix it. if anyone has an idea on how to proceed and get mongodb installed and running, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need to study up a bit on Gentoo if you intend to be proficient with it. You'll encounter this particular situation time and time again. First, did you read the man page that you were pointed you to ? (`man 5 portage`). Also, the Gentoo handbook is in my mind one of the best written linux related docs out there. 
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/USE <-- check it out.

For this situation, adding the line:
`dev-util/google-perftools-2.0-r2 -minimal`
to the end of `/etc/portage/package.use`, should get you up and running.